# Preventing an argument to be a complex number

Tags: haskell

I have a function like this:

```
hypergeom ::
     forall a. (Eq a, Fractional a)
  => Int  -- truncation weight
  -> a    -- alpha parameter (usually 2)
  -> [a]  -- "upper" parameters
  -> [a]  -- "lower" parameters
  -> [a]  -- variables (the eigen values)
  -> IO a
hypergeom m alpha a b x = do
  ......
```

I choosed the constraint `Fractional a` because I want the possibility to take `a` of type `Float`, `Double`, `Rational` or `Complex` (for example `Complex Double` or `Complex Rational`).

But now, I would like to allow `Complex` except for the parameter `alpha`. But if `a` is the type `Complex b` then `alpha` must be of type `b`. For example:

```
hypergeom ::
  => Int               -- truncation weight
  -> Double            -- alpha parameter (usually 2)
  -> [Complex Double]  -- "upper" parameters
  -> [Complex Double]  -- "lower" parameters
  -> [Complex Double]  -- variables (the eigen values)
  -> IO (Complex Double)
```

I hope I'm clear. How could I do that in a neat way ?

Comment: I’m not sure I understand the question. Do you mean that you want `alpha` to be anything **except** for `Complex`?

Comment: Oh, actually I think I understand now. If `a` (for example) is `Complex Double`, then you want `alpha` to be `Double`. Is that correct?

Comment: @bradm Yes, exactly.

Comment: Thanks! Another question: Is `a` restricted to types of the form `Complex (something)`, or can it be any `Fractional`? If it can be any `Fractional`, then is `alpha` of the same type?

Comment: @bradrn The other arguments can be any `Fractional`. And unless they are complex, `alpha` must be of the same type.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Code

If I am understanding correctly, you could use a type class with an associated type family for this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DefaultSignatures #-}

import           Data.Complex
import           Data.Ratio

class BaseFrac a where
  type family BaseFracType a
  type BaseFracType a = a -- Default type family instance (unless overridden)

  inject :: BaseFracType a -> a

  default inject :: BaseFracType a ~ a => BaseFracType a -> a
  inject = id

instance Integral a => BaseFrac (Ratio a)
instance BaseFrac Float
instance BaseFrac Double

-- etc...

instance Num a => BaseFrac (Complex a) where
  type BaseFracType (Complex a) = a

  inject x = x :+ 0


hypergeom ::
     forall a. (Eq a, Fractional a, BaseFrac a)
  => Int  -- truncation weight
  -> BaseFracType a    -- alpha parameter (usually 2)
  -> [a]  -- "upper" parameters
  -> [a]  -- "lower" parameters
  -> [a]  -- variables (the eigen values)
  -> IO a
hypergeom m alpha a b x = ...
```

It is possible that you will need to add additional methods to the type class, but I think `inject` should provide some important utility.

## Explanation

Writing this explanation, I realized that I probably compressed several ideas into a small area without giving the background information I should have given. Hopefully this helps and if you have any questions or are confused, you should let me know!

There are two main interacting ideas here. The first is that of a type class. I will assume some basic background on type classes (there are many resources going over the basics on that. If you would like, I can find some to link here).

The other is the idea of a type family. A type family is essentially a sort of function from types to types. Sometimes they are inside type classes (as they are here), but they don't have to be. Also, sometimes they are "open" and sometimes they are "closed" (if they are inside a type class, they are essentially open)

### Closed type families

I think it is instructive to look at a closed type family which is not in a type class first. Consider this:

```
type family Example :: * -> * where
  Example Int = Bool
  Example a   = a
```

This is very much like a regular Haskell function definition, except it happens to operate on types instead of values. If its input is the type `Int` it gives back the type `Bool`. Otherwise, it gives back the same type as the type it got as an argument.

We can see this using the `:kind!` command in GHCi:

```
λ > :kind! Example Int
Example Int :: *
= Bool
λ >
λ > :kind! Example Char
Example Char :: *
= Char
```

You can also think of type synonyms as a very restricted form of type family.

That type family is called "closed" because you cannot add more "equations" to its definition (just like a "regular" Haskell function).

### Open type families

But, you can also have "open" type families where you *can* add additional equations later on. For example:

```
type family OpenExample :: * -> *


type instance OpenExample [a] = a
type instance OpenExample Text = Char
type instance OpenExample IntSet = Int
-- ^ These just give you the "element type" inside some containers
```

We can later add on new equations with `type instance` (for instance, here if we add a new container type).

### Type families associated with type classes

This brings us to the sort of type family we have here: a type class with an associated type family. This is much like an open type family, but the input is constrained by the type class. Also, each equation is inside an instance of the type class.

I have provided a default type instance (the 2nd line of the `class` `BaseFrac`) which will automatically be used if none is provided. To write out the `Double` instance explicitly (without using this default) it looks like:

```
instance BaseFrac Double where
  type BaseFracType Double = Double
```

Note how similar this is to the `type instance` syntax.

I have also provided a default implementation for the `inject` method. This default can *only* be used if `BaseFracType a` is the *same* as `a` (this is what the constraint `BaseFracType a ~ a` means in the default signature).

This constraint *does* hold for any `instance` that uses the default `BaseFracType` definition (since it is just `type BaseFracType a = a`), which is why those "empty" instance definitions just automatically work.

So, for the instances given so far, `BaseFracType Double` is the same as `Double` (from the (default) type family definition used in the `Double` instance of the `BaseFrac` class) and `BaseFracType (Complex a)` is the same as `a` (from the type family instance definition given in the  `Complex a` instance of the `BaseFrac` class).

## What `inject` is for

That kind of explains *why* the types work out, but the next questions are *how do we actually use it* and why does `inject` matter? Luckily, the answers to those two questions are linked.

`inject` essentially provides you a way to put a "basic" ("1-dimensional") fractional value into whatever type that has an instance of the `BaseFrac` class.

For most types, this is just the identity function (since `Double` is already a "basic" fractional value, etc). For `Complex a`, this is different. It just constructs a complex number with a zero in its imaginary component and its argument as its real component. In that case, it is a function of type `inject :: Num a => a -> Complex a`.

Here is a simple example of `inject` in action based on the function you gave, with its full generality (this function works with any `BaseFrac` inputs):

```
hypergeom :: forall a. (Eq a, Fractional a, BaseFrac a)
  => Int
  -> BaseFracType a
  -> [a]
  -> [a]
  -> [a]
  -> IO a
hypergeom m alpha a b x = return (inject alpha * head a)
```

If the type variable `a` is `Rational`, then:

- `alpha` has type `Rational` (since `BaseFracType Rational` is the same as `Rational`)
- `inject alpha` also has type `Rational`
- The value of `inject alpha` is just `alpha`

If the type variable `a` is `Complex Double`, then:

- `alpha` has type `Double` (since `BaseFracType (Complex Double)` is the same as `Double`)
- `inject alpha` has the type `Complex Double`
- The value of `inject alpha` is `alpha :+ 0`

You can also use the GHCi `:kind!` command here:

```
λ > :kind! BaseFracType (Complex Double)
BaseFracType (Complex Double) :: *
= Double
```

If there's anything that's confusing, you can let me know and I should be able to clarify it.

## Additional material

There is some more information on type families [here](https://wiki.haskell.org/GHC/Type_families). Probably the most relevant sections there would be [the section on type synonym instances (which are the type families we talked about that were not associated with a type class)](https://wiki.haskell.org/GHC/Type_families#Detailed_definition_of_type_synonym_families), the subsection on [closed type families](https://wiki.haskell.org/GHC/Type_families#Closed_family_simplification) and  the subsection on [associated type families](https://wiki.haskell.org/GHC/Type_families#Associated_type_instances_2).

Note that page also talks about data families, which are not particularly relevant here (data families are kind of like "open" GADTs).

Comment: Thanks. This is beyond my Haskell skills, so I will try before sending my feedback.

Comment: I think you can say `instance RealFrac a => BaseFrac a` instead of many concrete instances (need FlexibleInstances)

Comment: @n.m. I assumed that runs into problems with overlapping instances, but I didn't try it (though I know sometimes instances are allowed to overlap to an extent). If it doesn't have those issues, that would definitely be convenient!

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent Let me know if you have any questions or if it doesn't work out!

Comment: (I can also add some more explanation to the answer when I get a bit of time. I'm going to go to bed soon, but I should have some time tomorrow.)

Comment: Unless someone adds `instance RealFrac Complex` or something equally weird I don't think there will be issues.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent I can try to explain how this works quickly: `BaseFrac` is a typeclass. Using an ‘associated type’ `BaseFracType a`, this contains an `inject` method which converts a `BaseFracType a` to an `a`. The `Complex` instance defines `BaseFracType (Complex a) = a`, so `inject` has type `Complex a -> a`; the other instances define `BaseFracType a = a`, so `inject` has type `a -> a`. (continued in next comment…)

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent (continued) Then in `hypergeom`, we constrain `a` to be a `BaseFrac`, so we can define `alpha` as being of type `BaseFracType a`; the implementation of `hypergeom` can then use `inject` to convert `alpha` to the same type as `a`. For more details, look up ‘type families’, which is the technique being used here.

Comment: @bradrn I suggest you move the explanation from the comment to the answer, if David is fine with that.

Comment: @MichaWiedenmann I do want to! But as you say I would like to wait for confirmation from David first.

Comment: @David do you object?

Comment: @bradrn I added some explanation. I personally lean towards thinking it is best to consolidate the same answer into the same SO answer, but I will leave that up to your discretion.

Comment: @n.m. It looks like that does immediately run into issues with overlapping instance errors. Whenever you have an instance that looks like `instance forall a. ... => SomeClass a` then you are *very* likely to run into overlapping instance issues (since GHC ignores the constraint when it searches for a matching type class `instance`).

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent I added a bit of explanation which hopefully helps. If you have any questions, you can let me know!

Comment: @ David. Thanks, this works. Thank you for the detailed explanations.

Answer (score 8):

Every Haskeller should know [the `vector-space` library](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-space-0.16/docs/Data-VectorSpace.html), and this is one application where it can be used.

```
hypergeom ::
     ∀ a. (VectorSpace a, Eq a, RealFrac (Scalar a))
  => Int       -- truncation weight
  -> Scalar a  -- alpha parameter (usually 2)
  -> [a]       -- "upper" parameters
  -> [a]       -- "lower" parameters
  -> [a]       -- variables (the eigen values)
  -> IO a
hypergeom m α a b x = do
  ......
```

This uses, in [the complex case](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vector-space-0.16/docs/src/Data.VectorSpace.html#line-143),

```
instance (RealFloat v, VectorSpace v) => VectorSpace (Complex v) where
  type Scalar (Complex v) = Scalar v
  s*^(u :+ v) = s*^u :+ s*^v
```

However, caveat: I personally am not a fan of that particular instance. Because complex numbers are a division algebra, it is quite often useful to consider them as a *scalar* type, i.e.

```
instance RealFloat a => VectorSpace (Complex a) where
  type Scalar (Complex a) = Complex a
  (*^) = (*)
```

The reason this is preferrable is that free vector spaces over the complex number (e.g. tuples) will then actually be complex vector spaces, not real vector spaces as they are as of version 0.16 of the library.

If the instance *were* defined as I would do it, then it would *not* work. This was actually [discussed](https://github.com/conal/vector-space/issues/20), maybe it'll change in the future.

Comment: This is a good answer. Before I wrote mine, I was trying to think of something like this that already exists but I couldn't come up with it (I looked in the `linear` package, but I don't think there's anything in `linear` for this kind of thing). Forgot about `vector-space`! The other thing that I was unsure of is, like you mentioned, complex numbers can be considered scalars (since they form a field) and I wasn't sure if something like this would quite work out since, even though complex numbers *are* a vector space over the reals, they are also a field (with vector spaces over it).

Comment: @David the `linear` style would be `Traversable v => Int -> s  -> [v s] -> ...`. But that would require to wrap real numbers in [`V1`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/linear-1.20.9/docs/Linear-V1.html), and is generally awkward.