# No instance for (RealFloat (Ratio Integer))

Tags: haskell

I'm using the stuff provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58056645/1100107) by @DavidYoung. I have a function:

```haskell
hypergeom ::
     forall a. (Eq a, Fractional a, BaseFrac a)
  => Int            -- truncation weight
  -> BaseFracType a -- alpha parameter (usually 2)
  -> [a]            -- "upper" parameters
  -> [a]            -- "lower" parameters
  -> [a]            -- variables (the eigenvalues)
  -> IO a
```

But when I run it with `a = Complex Rational` I get this error:

```
No instance for (RealFloat (Ratio Integer))
        arising from a use of `hypergeom'
```

What does that mean?

More precisely, here is the command I run:

```
ghci> import Data.Ratio
ghci> import Data.Complex
ghci> alpha = 2 % 1 :: Rational
ghci> a = 2 % 10 :+ 1 % 1 :: Complex Rational
ghci> b = 1 % 2 :+ 0 % 1 :: Complex Rational
ghci> c = 2 % 1 :+ 3 % 1 :: Complex Rational
ghci> x1 = 1 % 3 :+ 1 % 4 :: Complex Rational
ghci> x2 = 1 % 5 :+ 1 % 6 :: Complex Rational
ghci> hypergeom 10 alpha [a, b] [c] [x1, x2]

<interactive>:28:1: error:
    * No instance for (RealFloat (Ratio Integer))
        arising from a use of `hypergeom'
    * In the expression: hypergeom 10 alpha [a, b] [c] [x1, x2]
      In an equation for `it':
          it = hypergeom 10 alpha [a, b] [c] [x1, x2]
```

I'm pretty sure this worked in the past but I used `Data.Complex.Generic` (I don't use it anymore because it's not possible with a recent resolver).

Comment: The most usual `RealFloat` instance is `Double`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a trick. One can use the *cyclotomic* numbers. They contain the complex numbers with rational real and imaginary parts.

```haskell
instance BaseFrac Cyclotomic where
  type BaseFracType Cyclotomic = Rational
  inject x = gaussianRat x 0
```

example:

```
ghci> import Data.Complex.Cyclotomic
ghci> import Data.Ratio
ghci> alpha = 2%1
ghci> a = gaussianRat (2%7) (1%2)
ghci> b = gaussianRat (1%2) (0%1)
ghci> c = gaussianRat (2%1) (3%1)
ghci> x1 = gaussianRat (1%3) (1%4)
ghci> x2 = gaussianRat (1%5) (1%6)
ghci> hypergeom 10 alpha [a, b] [c] [x1, x2]
2636302089639370293242525873640165272590821169/2525202250482591646557047218608537600000000000 + 107068626184021125113299563281620084111568417/2525202250482591646557047218608537600000000000*e(4)
```

Answer (score 2):

Haven't run the code, but pretty sure the issue is this:

Use of `hypergeom` requires a `Fractional a` instance. The relevant instance for `Complex` is:

```hs
instance RealFloat a => Fractional (Complex a)
```

So, we need a `RealFloat Rational` instance. But `Rational = Ratio Integer`. So we need a `RealFloat (Ratio Integer)` instance. There is no such instance in scope. Hence, error.

Comment: Thanks. So there's no other choice than **complex-generic**? It worked. I tried **numeric-prelude** (<https://hackage.haskell.org/package/numeric-prelude-0.4.4/docs/Number-Complex.html>) with no luck.

Comment: Or **what4** (<https://hackage.haskell.org/package/what4-1.3/docs/What4-Utils-Complex.html>) but I have not been able to install it (issue with the **network** library).

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent unfortunately, I don't know of any instance off the top of my head that may be suitable for you. You could perhaps shoehorn in an instance for `RealFloat (Ratio Integer)`, although I'd imagine there's some reason it doesn't already exist